# django-allauth, Social authentication

Tags: django, django-allauth

This is login page after adding two social sites apps google and github. version of django-allauth is              0.54.0 and Django version 4.2.2

```
Sign In
Please sign in with one of your existing third party accounts. Or, sign up for a localhost account and sign in below:

Google
GitHub
or
Username: 
Password:
```

when i click on google, i see

```
Sign In Via Google
You are about to sign in using a third party account from Google.

Continue
```

i have to click on Continue to authenticate via google.

I don't need this middle page that means when i click on google or github it will directly go to authentication page. How can i customize it?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `SOCIALACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_GET` to `True`. As documented:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_GET (=False)
  Controls whether or not the endpoints for initiating a social login (for
  example, "/accounts/google/login/") require a POST request to initiate the
  handshake. For security considerations, it is strongly recommended to
  require POST requests.
```